# How to read Json response from the URL mentioned in Address Bar

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a project in MVC the default page displays list of students and Click on ID . It calls controller method `(StudentDetails/GetOverView/2323)` where 2323 Is the **ID**. After Clicking, I want to display details about Student 2323 in `StudentDetail` View page called `index.cshtml`.

My queston is how should i read the response ( Json ) after the page is `StudentDetail` page is loaded

GetOverView returns JSon as

```
{"rows":[{"Details":"Address","Data":"NewYork"},{"Details":"Registered Course","Data":"CSharp"}]}
```

Basically I want to display this data in a html table. but i stuck here

Comment: Well, how is your JSON fed to the page? Is it retrieved by the server? In which case, if you're on PHP, you can decode it to an array via `json_decode()` and iterate over it and output it. If it's retrieved over AJAX, you need JavaScript.

Comment: The data from MVC controller method called GetOverView .plz provide Jqvascrip to read this data.

Comment: Right, so if you're in a JavaScript environment then you need some JavaScript to decode the JSON (unless your framework decodes it for you) and then DOM-inject content. The way you do this depends on your library but the answer to your question, then, is essentially: how to handle JSON in JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry to ask basic Question: how to read server response in JavaScript  in $(document).ready(function () {}.

Comment: Study some tutorials on ajax. This question is far too broad.

Comment: As noted, this question is too broad. It depends how you're getting your server response in JavaScript. You need to learn about AJAX - that is the means of retrieving server responses into a JS environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

I would use `console.log(obj)` to view what is inside. Displaying is possible by adding the content of a JSON node inside a html element like a div or p tag or td as you said.

```
$("<td selector>").append("json element you want to append");
```